# Should I include special methods for a Python class UML?

Tags: python, uml

I wonder whether or not to include special methods in Python such as `__str__` or `___eq___`, etc, in a UML diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, do it only if they add some useful information to the readers of the said UML diagram.

I would say that, in general, any piece of documentation should only be written if it is useful for your users. Else it will only be in the way of finding other more important things.

In the case of doc strings, you should definitely write the `__hash__` method docstring. And **maybe** make a citation in the class docstring.

Comment: what if I am implementing __hash__ special method. Is it useful in this case to include it?

Comment: I would say "no". As it is expected that the hash function is well behaved and has the same semantics on any object. I would view it as an implementation detail.

Comment: A docstring on the method, sure. On its class, it depends on how relevant this implementation is. As with the UML, you should increase the signal/noise to the user of the documentation.